# How to conjugate "fhtagn" in R'lyehian?

Tags: grammar, rlyehian

The accepted translation of Lovecraft's "Cthulhu fhtagn" seems to be "Cthulhu dreams".

How would one conjugate "fhtagn" to get the word derivations "dream", "dreamer", "dreaming".

[This answer](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/371/what-is-rlyehian-based-on) had a helpful link for translations, but not much in the way of deriving conjugates.

Comment: fyi, not all derivations are conjugations; suggest you look up the latter word.

Comment: Conjugate seemed to be the closest descriptive word I could find to describe this word derivation when I posted this. If there's a more accurate word, please share.

Answer (score 5):

Lovecraft probably didn't think about grammar, and we certainly don't have enough material to reconstruct one. Could also be like Sindarin, where Tolkien wrote much, but never released any specification of the language. Quote from the threat you linked: "To my knowledge, we only have the transcription in the Latin alphabet" (comment from Sparksbet).